# Multiple monitor windows overlapping one taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Windows is so weird.  To the left of the blue line on the image below is monitor A, and to the right of the blue line is monitor B.  You'll notice that the the windows are in front of the taskbar on monitor A, but that they drop behind it on monitor B.

[image: Dual Monitors with windows overlapping one taskbar]

Does anyone know if this is a bug, or a setting that I can influence in some way?

This is Windows 10.0.17134.  Two 21 inch monitors

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Press Ctrl alt del to open task manager, find the `windows explorer` process, right click and restart it.

Comment: Possible dublicate? did you try https://superuser.com/questions/1163969/windows-10-taskbar-is-not-always-on-top ?

Comment: @Albin - that fixed it

Comment: @dgo glad I could help. Which fix was it? changing the taskbars position?

Comment: @Albin - yup -> moved it to the top, back down.  Then moved it back down

Comment: @dgo that was it for me as well... :)  I put it into a nice answer, feel free to accept...

Comment: @dgo completely forgot about the vote, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the position of the taskbar and then change it back:

- Right Click the task bar,
- go to properties
- set it to show at the top of the screen (or somewhere where it's not right now).
- Then I set it back to it's original position

should solve the problem in most cases ([see here](https://superuser.com/a/1228997/201818) for original post).